# WP8 keep forgetting email passwords

Tags: email, password

I have 2 email accounts, Office 365 and Yahoo!+

Having problems with both, usually when sending email. Sometimes I send picture in email and it wouldn't go through. Go back to email on a phone - it asks for password. I do check "save" checkbox but it seems like it keeps forgetting passwords.

Comment: What phone are you using? Has an update occurred recently?

Comment: Nokia Lumia 925, yes, updated recently on 7/19 or so

Comment: And have you always had the problem since getting the phone?